# Queue in C, bad printing

Tags: c, queue

thanks a lot for help with stack, now I have written queue by myself.. But I have just one problem. When I'm adding just one item and I want to print it, program is printing this number in infinity. What's wrong with my push/print function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct Element Element;
typedef struct Element
{
    int value;
    Element* next;
} Element;

Element* first = NULL;
Element* last = NULL;

void pop();
void push(int x);
void printqueue();

int main()
{
    int x;
    int warunek;
    do
    {
        printf("\nMENU\n");
        printf("1. Push[1]\n2. Pop[2]\n3. Print[3]\n0. Wyjdz[0]\n");
        printf("Podaj warunek: ");
        scanf("%d", &warunek);
        switch(warunek)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                printf("Give a number: ");
                scanf("%d", &x);
                push(x);
            }
            break;
            case 2: pop();
            break;
            case 3: printqueue();
            break;
            default: printf("Bad value.\n");
        }
    }
    while(warunek != 0);
    return 0;
}

void push(int x)
{
    Element* pNewItem = (Element*)malloc(sizeof(Element));
    pNewItem->value = x;
    pNewItem->next = NULL;
    if(first == NULL && last == NULL)
    {
        first = last = pNewItem;
    }
    last->next = pNewItem;
    last = pNewItem;
}

void pop()
{
    Element* pNewItem = first;
    if(first == NULL)
        printf("Queue is empty.\n");
    else if(first == last)
        first = last = NULL;
    else
        first = first->next;
    free(pNewItem);
}


void printqueue()
{
    Element* temp = first;
    printf("\nContent of queue\n");
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", temp->value);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: `last->next = pNewItem;
    last = pNewItem;` --> `else { last->next = pNewItem;
    last = pNewItem; }`

Comment: If you select `0`, it is said to be `Bad value.`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's this line:

```
last->next = pNewItem;
```

when `first == last`, you create a cycle here -> put it in an `else` branch.

Answer (score 0):

The function `push` is wrong. The statements after the if

```
last->next = pNewItem;
last = pNewItem;
```

need to be enclosed in an else statement.

The function can look the following way

```
void push(int x)
{
    Element* pNewItem = (Element*)malloc(sizeof(Element));
    pNewItem->value = x;
    pNewItem->next = NULL;


    if( last == NULL )
    {
        first = last = pNewItem;
    }
    else
    {
        last = last->next = pNewItem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void push(int x)
{
Element* pNewItem = (Element*)malloc(sizeof(Element));
pNewItem->value = x;
if(first == NULL && last == NULL)
{
    first = last = pNewItem;
}
else{
last->next = pNewItem;
last = pNewItem;
last.next = NULL;
}
}
```

You got it write there is problem in push. Consider this push function this is just modified version of your push. You can directly use it instead of your push. Note there are three changes in push functions.

Comment: Presented by you the function implementation has a bug.